# ¿Cargar una dependencia en todos los archivos?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

tengo una función para logs en un archivo
 `./util/logger.js`
, ese archivo exporta la función y hago un

```
const Logger = require('../util/logger.js');
```

en cada archivo para poder usarla, 
¿Cómo puedo cargar esa función de forma global en toda mi app para no tener que hacer un `require` en cada archivo?

Quizá pueda especificarla en el package.json, pero no se como,

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Es muy sencillo: en el navegador, existe la variable global `window`, accesible desde todas partes ¿ verdad ?

Pues en node tenemos la variable `global`:

```
// index.js

global.cucu = function( ) {
  console.log( 'cucu' );
}

const otro = require( './otro.js' );

otro.run( );
```

```
// otro.js

module.exports = {
  run: function( ) {
    cucu( );
  }
};
```

Ahora, si ejecutamos `node index.js`, obtenemos la salida ...

> cucu

Como vemos, `cucu( )` ha estado disponible desde el archivo `otro.js`, sin necesidad de hacer ningún `require( )`.

Hay que tener cuidado con los nombres que usamos ... `global` es, efectivamente, **global**, por lo que un posible `require( 'algo' )` puede *machacar* nuestra variable con otro valor. O nosotros *machacar* una variable ya presente, de las que `node` coloca automaticamente ahí (por ejemplo, `global.console.log`).